# How do I explicitly define the NSPersistentStore and CKRecordZone.ID for @FetchRequest in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, cloudkit, fetchrequest

I am updating my App to support sharing of Cloudkit data with other iCloud users.  Is there a way to specify the NSPersistentStore and the CKRecordZone.ID for my fetch?  I do not see an option in the predicate.

```
struct MyView: View {

    @FetchRequest<CD_MyManagedObject> private var fetchRequest: FetchedResults< CD_MyManagedObject >

    init() {
        _fetchRequest = FetchRequest(entity: CD_MyManagedObject.entity()
                                    , sortDescriptors: []
                                    , predicate: myfetchPredicate())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify the zone because that is set automatically but you can choose the store with:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506518-affectedstores

You need to retain the `NSFetchRequest` object somewhere so you can reuse it in the `FetchRequest` struct init every time the `View` struct is init otherwise it's a memory leak.